# Filter after grouping columns in Power BI

Tags: reporting, business-intelligence, powerbi, microsoft-reporting

I want to accomplish something easy to understand (and maybe easy to do but I can't find a way...).

I have a table which represents the date when a client has bought something.
Let's have this example:

```
=============================================
 Purchase_id |  Purchase_date  | Client_id 
=============================================
  1          |    2016/03/02   |       1     
---------------------------------------------
  2          |    2016/03/02   |       2   
---------------------------------------------
  3          |    2016/03/11   |       3     
---------------------------------------------
```

I want to create a single number card which will be the **average of purchase realised by day**.

So for this example, the result would be:

**Result** = 3 purchases / 2 different days = **1.5**

I managed doing it by grouping in my query by Purchase_date and my new column is the number of rows.
It gives me the following query:

```
==================================
 Purchase_date |  Number of rows 
==================================
  2016/03/02   |       2    
----------------------------------
  2016/03/11   |       1   
----------------------------------
```

Then I put the field **Number of rows** in a single number card, selecting "Average".
 I have to precise that I am using **Direct Query** with SQL Server.

But the problem is that I want to have a filter on the **Client_id**. And once I do the grouping, I lose this column.

Is there a way to have this **Client_id** as a parameter?

Maybe even the fact of grouping is not the right solution here.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you use the function Distinct COunt, in dax with powerQuery? if yes, you can use the first table an create a measure that divide distinct count transaction/ distinctcounday and filter by day and Customer.

Comment: what happens if you add client_id to the power bi report using as a slicer, then select a single value of client_id?  does it do what you expect or something different?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a measure to calculate this average.
From Power BI's [docs](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-desktop-measures/):

> The calculated results of measures are always changing in response to
>   your interaction with your reports, allowing for fast and dynamic
>   ad-hoc data exploration

This means filtering client_id's will change the measure accordingly.

Here is an easy way of defining this measure:

```
Result = DISTINCTCOUNT(tableName[Purchase_date])/DISTINCTCOUNT(tableName[Purchase_id])
```